# Converting array of chars to array of ints

Tags: c, arrays, char, integer

I have this homework and it's been giving me a headache because I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Basically, it should read a certain number of chars, being 'x' the last char and store them into heap memory.

After that, the program should sort it using the ASCII table.

Then, it should read every four chars as an int. The number of chars of the input will always be a multiple of four, so it will work everytime.

Last, but not least important, it should print the integer numbers.

My problem is: the program is printing the integers in the wrong order.

Here it goes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int cont = 1;
    int i, j, tmp;
    char c;
    char *dados = NULL;

    do
    {
        scanf("%s", &c);
        dados = (char*)realloc(dados, sizeof(char)*cont);
        dados[cont - 1] = c;
        cont++;
    }
    while(c != 'x');

    for (i = 0; i < (cont - 1); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < (cont - i - 1); j++)
        {
            if (dados[j] > dados[j + 1])
            {
                tmp = dados[j];
                dados[j] = dados[j + 1];
                dados[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    int *charInt = (int*)dados;
    int aux = sizeof(int);

    for(i = 1; i <= (cont - 1); i = i + aux)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *charInt);
        ++charInt;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May be a good idea to give some sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: It would be nice to add some comments into code.

Comment: Tell me if i understand, you sort a char array according to the asci value, then you want to print these value in the order ?

Comment: There are other problems with this code, but order of ints looks, more or less, fine for me.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &c)` is dreadfully wrong.  You are scanning an indeterminate number of chars and trying to store the result into the space reserved for a single one.  Moreover, you are skipping leading whitespace, and even if you only got one char at a time, you would still need storeage for at least two, because the `%s` field descriptor instructs scanf that the scanned value must be a nul-terminated string.  Use `c = getchar()` instead.

Comment: 1. `sizeof(char)` is `1`. 2. You don't have to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some modifications. The following code should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int cont = 0;
    int i, j, tmp;
    char c;
    char *dados = NULL;
    dados = malloc(sizeof(char));
    do
    {
        scanf("%s", &c);
        dados = (char*)realloc(dados, sizeof(char)*cont);
        dados[cont] = c;
        cont++;

    }
    while(c != 'x');
    for (i = 0; i < (cont - 2); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < (cont - i - 2); j++)
        {
            if (dados[j] > dados[j + 1])
            {
                tmp = dados[j];
                dados[j] = dados[j + 1];
                dados[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    char *charInt = (char*)dados;
    int aux = sizeof(char);

    for(i = 0; i <= (cont - 2)*aux; i = i + aux)
    {
        printf("%d\n",*charInt);

        ++charInt;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer keeps many of the original's bugs (buffer overflows, etc).

Comment: I'm aware of the bugs from the original code.I tried to make it work with the fewest corrections, I just noticed the buffer overflow.